# How to hide green faces selection in UV editor?

Tags: uv, faces, uv-image-editor, selection-tools, select

The green faces remain even when I'm not selecting, is there any way to avoid this?

[image]

And even when I'm not in UV Sync

[image]

Comment: Without UV sync, you have to deselect the 3D model to make everything dissappear, just select the faces that you need on the 3D model, or press H to hide faces

Comment: I know but that doesn't make the green selection go away

Comment: Disable `Faces` in Overlays Menu (two circles in header right) ?